# Duplicate form generated in a for loop not getting required value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that duplicates via a for loop based on the number of people entered for registration. There is a field on the form with a select dropdown. There is also a text field that displays the value of the selected dropdown item. This is done via javascript.

```
<?Php for ($i=0; $i<$totalpersons; $i++) { ?>
    <div>
        <span><label>SURNAME *</label></span>
        <span><input name="surname[]" type="text" class="textbox" id="surname" required></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>FIRST NAME *</label></span>
        <span><input name="firstname[]" type="text" class="textbox" id="firstname" required></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>OTHER NAME</label></span>
        <span><input name="othername[]" type="text" class="textbox" id="othername"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>DOB *</label></span>
        <span><input name="dob[]" type="text" class="textbox" id="dob" required></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>GENDER *</label></span>
        <span>                          
            <select name="gender[]" id="gender"  tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true" required style="width: 100%; display: block;height:50px;padding:10px;">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>AGE RANGE *</label></span>
        <span>                          
            <select name="screeningamount[]" id="screeningamount"  tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true" required style="width: 100%; display: block;height:50px;padding:10px;"  onClick="GetSelectedValue()">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="25000" id="0yrsto4yrs">0 YEAR TO 4 YEARS</option>
                <option value="27000" id="5yrsto10yrs">5 YEARS TO 10 YEARS</option>
                <option value="31000" id="11yrsto14yrs">11 YEARS TO 14 YEARS</option>
                <option value="35000" id="15yrsabove">15 YEARS AND ABOVE</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>AMOUNT DUE(₦):</label></span>
        <span><input name="amount" type="text" class="textbox" id="amount" readonly></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>E-MAIL *</label></span>
        <span><input name="email[]" type="text" class="textbox" id="email" required></span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_3"></div>
    <div>
        <span><label>PHONE *</label></span>
        <span><input name="phone[]" type="text" class="textbox" id="phone" required></span>
    </div>
<?Php } ?>
```

The challenge I have is this, if the number of forms generated is above one, when I select a value from the Age Range select dropdown, the text box for the first form is populated correctly as it should be. but when I select a value from the select dropdown on the second form, the textbox is not populated.

the javascript code used is below:

```
function GetSelectedValue(){
    var select = document.getElementById('screeningamount');
    var input = document.getElementById('amount');

    select.onchange = function() {
        input.value = select.value;
    }
}
```

How do I solve the problem? I need each form irrespective of the number of forms generated, to be able to display the value of the select dropdown on each form

Comment: You should know that HTML attribute "id" must be unique on whole page. Try adding numbers to your ids when duplicating fields so JavaScript can handle the form.

Comment: @SenadMeškin Yes i understand that but dont know how to go about it. If the form was finite, i would simply have just addeda number to each forms id to differentiate it. but the form is generated via the for loop.

Comment: @SenadMeškin i think it can be solved using javasript, but i dont know how to go about it as i dont know javascript that much

Comment: id="surename'.$i.'"